# Select only the id of text box

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to select only the id of textbox after that to insert into database..For example I have `echo $t['id']` `echo $t['name']` but I want select only the id. Is there any solution?I want to get from li elements only the $t['id'] after that to insert into database...If I write only $t['id'] I can insert into database but If I write $t['id']-$t['name'] I get an error...So I need to get only the $t['id'] from text box

**HTML:**

```
 <input type="text" name="dropdiv" id="dropdiv" style="width:605" />

  <div id="dragdiv">
      <ul id="allItems">
                    <?php if($tags): ?>
                        <?php foreach($tags as $t): ?>
                            <li id="node" runat="server" value="$t['id']">
                                <?php echo $t['id']?><?php echo $t['name'] ?>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?> 
            </ul> 
        </div>                
        <br />
```

**JQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#dragdiv li").draggable({
           helper: "clone",
           cursor: "move",
           revert: "invalid"
       });

       initDroppable($("#dropdiv"));

       function initDroppable($elements) {
           $elements.droppable({
               activeClass: "ui-state-default",
               hoverClass: "ui-drop-hover",
               accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",

               over: function (event, ui) {
                   var $this = $(this);
               },
               drop: function (event, ui) {
                   var $this = $(this);
                   if ($this.val() == '') {
                       $this.val(ui.draggable.text().trim());
                       ui.draggable.remove();
                   } else {
                       $this.val($this.val() + " " + ui.draggable.text().trim());
                       ui.draggable.remove();
                   }

               }
           });
       }
        });
    </script>
```

CodeIgniter

```
$tags      =     $this->input->post('dropdiv');
        $theid     =     $this->db->insert_id();
 $tags_arr = array();
        $theid = $this->db->insert_id();
        $tags_arr = explode(' ',$tags);
        foreach ($tags_arr as $t) 
        {          
            $tag_SQL = $t;
            $this->db->query("insert into tags_in_news (news_id, tag_id) values ('{$theid}','{$tag_SQL}')");
        }
```

Help me please guys...

Comment: your question is not clear, please try to point what exactly you want?

Comment: Clarify please, what exactly are you trying to do? what do you mean select the id?

Comment: Are echo $t['id'] echo $t['name'] text boxes?

Comment: I want to get from <li> elements only the $t['id'] after that to insert into database...If I write only $t['id'] I can insert into database but If I write $t['id']-$t['name'] I get an error...So I need to get only the $t['id'] from text box

Comment: I have one textbox which has two echo but I need to get only one the $t['id']

Comment: I'm also confused: Are you trying to get the value of $t['id'] with Javascript or with php? Because you are talking about putting it into the database.

Comment: [0]=>Array([id]=>1 [name]=>first),[1]=>Array([id]=>2 [name=>last])....

Answer (score 0):

I see only one textbox in your code. So, just do:

```
$("#dropdiv").method();
```

Read more about jQuery selectors here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm slowly starting to understand. Replace `ui.draggable.text()` with `ui.draggable.attr('value')`, because you're trying to get that. But even better, replace the `value` attribute with a `data-id` attribute in your html (this way it's correct html).

html:

```
<li id="node" runat="server" data-id="$t['id']">
```

js:

```
if ($this.val() == '') {
   $this.val(ui.draggable.attr('data-id').trim());
   ui.draggable.remove();
} else {
   $this.val($this.val() + " " + ui.draggable.attr('data-id').trim());
   ui.draggable.remove();
}
```

Comment: It's ok but in textbox displays only id...is any solution to do that with php?thx

Comment: Use the textbox to display with the `.text()` method, and save the value into a `<input type="hidden" />` field instead.